# CSS overlap multiple divs

Tags: css, position

[image]

Hello! I would like to accomplish this with a circle div. I know how to accomplish positioning with absolute and relative in 1 div, but if i want to make this out of two divs and make the circle overlapping these two divs is there any easy/smart way to go in CSS?

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS here so we could see what you've tried so far?

Comment: Are you trying to line up two semi-circles, or position one whole circle at the center point of the divs?

Comment: I'm trying to position the whole circle at the center point of the divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.top {
  background: red;
}

.bottom {
  background: black;
}

.circle {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```